# Matlab MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error in C# on one system

Tags: c#, matlab

I made a very simple program with C#  VS2017 and Matlab 2012b:

```
namespace TestConMatlab
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var matlab = new MatlabFunction();
                double[] data = { 1, 2, 3 };
                double[,] r = (double[,])matlab.doMedian(data.ToArray());
                Console.Out.Write("OK: " + r.ToString());                
            } catch( Exception ex )
            {
                Console.Out.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This program run on mulitple PC, but on one computer I have :

```
System.Exception:

... MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error ...
Undefined function 'doMedian' for input arguments of type 'double'..


   at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR.EvaluateFunction(String functionName, Int32 numArgsOut, Int32 numArgsIn, MWArray[] argsIn)
   at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR.EvaluateFunction(String functionName, Object[] argsIn)
   at MatlabFunctionNative.MatlabFunction.doMedian(Object input)
   at TestConMatlab.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\TestConMatlab\Program.cs:line 18
```

Of course I have installed the same Matlab MCR v8.0. I have trace some API call with procmon but I did not find solution.

Comment: With Matlab 2017 and later it is backward compatible.  So when you change version of matlab you do not need to modify existing code.  Also on same machine you can installed multiple version of the run time library.  It sound like you do not have the 17.0 runtime library install on machine that is not working.  Or you installed for only one user and not all users.

Comment: In case of not installed MCR I have "System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'mclmcrrt8_0.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" @jdwend

Comment: Sounds like you did not install the correct version of the runtime library.  The installed version has to be the same as the version of Matlab that was used to compile the dll.

Comment: I installed the same version as on the other PCs, I even desintaller reinstaller, reboot. Is there any way to get the log of the MCR loading?

Comment: Where is the matlab dll?  Did you put in dame folder as the c# executable?

Comment: All files are in the same folder MatlabFunctionNative.dll, MWArray.dll, TestConMatlab.exe, TestConMatlab.exe.config, TestConMatlab.pdb.

Comment: Matlab will default all numbers to double.  So you have a double in matlab and the parameter list in c# is int.  So either change parameter in c# to double or convert in matlab. See : https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: Where do you see int ?

Comment: at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR.EvaluateFunction(String functionName, Int32 numArgsOut, Int32 numArgsIn, MWArray[] argsIn)

Comment: EvaluateFunction is a internal function, see my code I'm only call doMedian(), and this code work on other machine.

Comment: Do all machine have same version of Matlab installed?   A dll will work under 2 conditions 1) The same version of Matlab is installed on build and deploy machine 2) When Matlab the version of Matlab is not installed on deploy machine you need to install the same version of the Run Time library that code was used to build.  You can have multiple versions of Matlab and multiple versions of the Run Time installed on a machine.

Comment: Same version Matlab 2012b => MCR installter v8.0 x86.

Comment: What versions are on working machines?  Matlab make two releases a year.  An A version released in teh spring and a B version in the fall.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB?force_isolation=true.  Typing "ver" in a command window will give version information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted the folder *C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\%USER%\mcrCache8.0*
Remove MCR and delete manualy *C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB*, and after restart, program work !